# How to add the gcc linker fixed address into linker file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

In my c program :

```
int a[1024] __attribute__((section(".myvarloc")));
```

I studied a few documents and came to know that I should add the below section in the linker section. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

```
MEMORY
{
        MYMEMORY(rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x0041c620 ,  LENGTH = 30
}

.myvars (NOLOAD) :
{
  *(. myvarloc)

} > MYMEMORY
```

I am using eclipse ide.

Comment: could you explain that exactly where should I do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct spelling.

try `*(.myvarloc)` instead of `*(. myvarloc)`.

The link just matches the section names in the `*()` environment and it can't match with your script..